# Why do I get "Error in (function (.Data, ...) : 'names' attribute [5] must be the same length as the vector [1]" when building a package?

Tags: r, devtools

I'm trying to create my first real package, and I'm having newbie problems.  I've skimmed Hadley's book on packaging, read Hillary Parker's post and Karl Broman's post, watched Rory Winston's video, and more, but I ended up stuck.  I then started over with what I thought would be a simple example, which I've uploaded to GitHub as https://github.com/bharris-fs/testpkg.  I'm using a current R on Debian Jessie, I'm using devtools, and I'm using ESS.

Here's a trimmed-down set of commands I used to get to this point:

```
library(devtools)
library(roxygen2)
devtools::create('testpkg')
setwd('testpkg')
devtools::document()
devtools::load_all()
```

At this point, `help(package='testpkg')` seemed to give me what I expected.  I then added `one.R`, which contains one documented function.

```
devtools::use_package('arm')
devtools::use_package('stats')
devtools::document()
devtools::load_all()    
setwd('..')
devtools::install('testpkg')
library('testpkg')
?displaylm
```

and that gets me

```
Error in (function (.Data, ...)  : 
  'names' attribute [5] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

I also recognize that `devtools::install('testpkg')` and `library(testpkg)` seem superfluous, but in working on a more real package, `load_all` didn't seem to reload the package.  I was going to ask about that, but then my "simple" example produced that error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8       LC_NUMERIC=C             
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.utf8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.utf8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.utf8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.utf8       LC_NAME=C                
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C           
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C      

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] testpkg_0.0.0.9000   arm_1.9-3            lme4_1.1-12         
[4] Matrix_1.2-8         MASS_7.3-45          roxygen2_6.0.1      
[7] devtools_1.12.0.9000

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.9         xml2_1.1.1          whisker_0.3-2      
 [4] magrittr_1.5        splines_3.3.2       pkgload_0.0.0.9000 
 [7] lattice_0.20-34     R6_2.2.0            minqa_1.2.4        
[10] stringr_1.2.0       tools_3.3.2         grid_3.3.2         
[13] pkgbuild_0.0.0.9000 nlme_3.1-131        coda_0.19-1        
[16] git2r_0.18.0        withr_1.0.2         commonmark_1.2     
[19] abind_1.4-5         rprojroot_1.2       digest_0.6.12      
[22] assertthat_0.1      crayon_1.3.2        callr_1.0.0.9000   
[25] nloptr_1.0.4        memoise_1.0.0       stringi_1.1.2      
[28] compiler_3.3.2      desc_1.1.0          backports_1.0.5
```

Comment: @chinsoon12, thanks.  I had seen that command and then forgotten about it.  That only makes it easier than doing the `git remote add origin ...` and `git push -u origin master`, though, right?  What I pushed still has that error, at least on my system.

Comment: @chinsoon12: Oops: I read too quickly.  `install_github` gets a package from GitHub.

Comment: Yes.  It claimed to build okay.  `man/displaylm.Rd` looks reasonable.  `NAMESPACE` contains `export(displaylm)` and only that.   `DESCRIPTION` is the original template with the added `Imports:` section.  BUT I get the above error when I type `?displaylm`, and `example(displaylm)` gives the warning `In example("displaylm") : no help found for ‘displaylm’`.

Comment: i managed to run the following without any error `devtools::install_github("bharris-fs/testpkg"); library(testpkg); ?displaylm` and you might want to use `@import arm` in the roxygen code for `displaylm` rather than type it manually in DESCRIPTION

Comment: That's interesting.  I did the same thing you did, and I got the same error as above in response to `?displaylm`.  `example(displaylm)` did work, though.  I didn't think GitHub did anything special to the package, though; you should be able to build a package locally and then use it, right?   Incidentally, I didn't type anything into DESCRIPTION yet.  As in the trace above, I used `devtools::use_package`.

Comment: Maybe remove the local version of your library first. Use 'remove.package'

Comment: @chinsoon12; that worked!  I'm still puzzled what I'm doing wrong, because I've never read that you /have/ to upload a package to GitHub to make it work, but at least I can make this one work.  I'll look at it again tomorrow.

Comment: I guess you were making changes on your local copy which fails to build because the error. And installing from github did not overwrite the local copy.